# pglogical: list array/schema/table part of the replication sets?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

Is there a way to list the Array/schemas which have been added to the replication_set?

```
# SELECT * FROM pglogical.replication_set;
   set_id   | set_nodeid |       set_name       | replicate_insert | replicate_update | replicate_delete | replicate_truncate
------------+------------+----------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------
 1921995266 | 1338498914 | default              | t                | t                | t                | t
 4027572585 | 1338498914 | default_insert_only  | t                | f                | f                | t
 3823354649 | 1338498914 | ddl_sql              | t                | f                | f                | f
 1724847149 | 1338498914 | replication_set | t                | t                | t                | t
(4 rows)
# SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables('replication_set', ARRAY['public'],true);
replication_set_add_all_tables
--------------------------------
 t
(1 row)

# SELECT pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables('idev_replication_set', ARRAY['catalog2'],true);
replication_set_add_all_tables
--------------------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hey @Gowthamakanthan did you get an answer to this?

Comment: @Yituo .. Nope. still searching.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from pglogical.replication_set_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, thats help me to list the tables which added to the replication set. do we have similar commands to list the schema as well?